# Merge excel files (with same name) into one spreadsheet from multiple folders vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to merge excel workbooks into one workbook and save it in a different folder based on the exact same name of the file. Please find an example below. Can someone advise?

Folder Data contains three sub-folders:

- Subfolder 1
- Subfolder 2
- Subfolder 3

Subfolder 1 contains:

- Company 1.xlsx
- Company 2.xlsx
- Company 3.xlsx

Subfolder 2 contains:

- Company 1.xlsx
- Company 2.xlsx

Subfolder 3 contains:

- Company 1.xlsx
- Company 4.xlsx

Output folder:

- Company 1.xlsx
- Company 2.xlsx
- Company 3.xlsx
- Company 4.xlsx

This is my code so far but have not managed to copy the worksheets to one central file.

```
Sub Mergedatasets()

Dim fPATH As String:    fPATH = Sheets("Instructions").Range("C16") & "\Split spreadsheets\"
Dim FSO As Object:      Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim FLD As Object:      Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(fPATH)
Dim SubFLDRS As Object: Set SubFLDRS = FLD.SubFolders
Dim SubFLD As Object
Dim wbMain As Workbook: Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long

For Each SubFLD In SubFLDRS
Filename = Dir(fPATH & SubFLD.Name & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fPATH & SubFLD.Name & "\" & Filename)

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A1:A" & LR).EntireRow.copy
    wbMain.Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next ws

Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbData.Close False
Next SubFLD

Set wbMain = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks, Jeroen

Comment: Shouldn't `ActiveWorkbook` be `wbData`, i.e. the workbook you have opened and want to copy data from.

Comment: Will achieve the same result with both scenarios, since the workbook is already open that I want to copy the data from. I basically want to open all excel documents with the same name and copy the first and only worksheet to a new excel document

Comment: Main problem is now that wbMain.sheets(ws.name) etc has a run-time error with subscript out of range

Comment: So `wbMain` doesn't have a sheet named whatever `ws` is?

Comment: nowadays, we use PowerQuery to do this

Comment: I agree with @norie, there is no reason to use `ActiveWorkbook` when you have already set a perfectly good variable to use. One potential problem with using `ActiveWorkbook` is that you could inadvertently change it while the macro is running if you happen to be clicking around in Excel. Probably not a huge chance, but it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Don't you need to obtain as unique files name exists workbooks? Your code tries copying everything in ` wbMain`. Am I missing something...?

Comment: @FaneDuru: you are correct want to obtain the file names of the workbooks and not to copy it to wbMain

Comment: I am driving now. I wjll try providing an answer, after some hours, whwn I will be at home...

Comment: What is the goal of this snippet of code? Is it to have a tab for each unique filename, and to create a new file in the output folder for each tab? If that is the case you can use `Filename` to identify it. Using `ws.name` will give you the name of the `Worksheet` (ie, the caption on the tab).

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next solution:

```
Sub mergeSameNameWbDiffFld()
   'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
   Dim wbMain As Workbook, wbData As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsAdd As Worksheet, LR As Long
   Dim col As Collection, El As Variant, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, arr, arr1, i As Long, k As Long
   Dim fPATH  As String, wbName As String
   
   fPATH = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Folders"      'the main folder path
   Set col = GetFiles(fPATH, "*.xlsx", True) 'place in collection all existing files from subfolders

   For Each El In col                        'iterate between collection elements and place unique file names in dictionary
        arr = Split(El, "|")                 'split the path from the file name
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(1)) Then      'if file name does not exist in dictionary
            dict.Add arr(1), arr(0)          'add it with subfolder path as item
        Else
           dict(arr(1)) = dict(arr(1)) & "|" & arr(0) 'add the next subfolder path separated by "|"
        End If
   Next
   Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'some optimization
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1           'iterate between the dictionary elements (keys and items):
        arr = Split(dict.items(i), "|")  'place subfolder paths in an array
        For Each El In arr               'iterate between the paths (of the same file name):
            Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(El & dict.Keys(i)) 'open the file (subfolder path + file name)
            k = k + 1                    'increment the paths number
            If k = 1 Then                'first one is transformed in the workbook to collect the others sheets, too
                wbData.saveas fPATH & "\_" & dict.Keys(i) 'place an "_" character in the name to be able to open the other similar files
                Set wbMain = wbData      'set the workbook to collect the other similar files sheets content
            Else
                For Each ws In wbData.Sheets       'iterate between all existing sheets
                    LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
                    If LR > 1 Then                 'skip the sheets not having data
                        arr1 = ws.UsedRange.Value  'place the used range in an array (much faster than copying)
                        On Error Resume Next       'avoid an error if the next line will not find an existing sheet name
                         Set wsAdd = wbMain.Sheets(ws.Name) 'try to set the sheet if it already exists
                         If err.Number <> 0 Then    'if it does not exist
                            err.Clear               'clear the error
                            Set wsAdd = wbMain.Sheets.Add(Before:=wbMain.Sheets(1)) 'insert a new sheet
                            wsAdd.Name = ws.Name    'name it as ws name
                         End If
                        On Error GoTo 0             'let VBA to raise an error if the case
                        'copy the used range at the end of existing:
                        wsAdd.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arr1), UBound(arr1, 2)).Value = arr1
                    End If
                Next
                wbData.Close False      'close the file where from the used range has been extracted (without saving)
            End If
        Next
        wbName = wbMain.fullName 'memorize the full name (containing the diferentiation character: "_")
        wbMain.Close True: k = 0       'close the workbook (saving it) and reiinialize k variable
        'eliminate "_" character from the name:
        Name wbName As fPATH & "\" & dict.Keys(i)
   Next i
   Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Private Function GetFiles(startFolder As String, filePatternExtension As String, _
        Optional boolSubFolders As Boolean = False) As Collection 'ret a collection of file objects, given a starting fodler and pattern extension
    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fPATH
    Dim colFiles As New Collection, colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    
    Do While colSub.count > 0
        Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(colSub(1)) 'create folder object form the first element of collection
        colSub.Remove 1                     'remove that first object of collection
        
        If boolSubFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.path:
            Next subFldr
        End If
        
        If fldr.path <> startFolder Then     'skip the files from the start folder
            fPATH = fldr.path
            If Right(fPATH, 1) <> "\" Then fPATH = fPATH & "\"
            f = dir(fPATH & filePatternExtension)
            Do While Len(f) > 0
                colFiles.Add fPATH & "|" & f 'separate the subfolder path from file name using "|" separator
                f = dir()
            Loop
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetFiles = colFiles
End Function
```

If difficult to add the required reference, please firstly run the next code (once) which will automatically add it. Save the workbook and reference will remain. Then, run the above code:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
  If err.Number = 32813 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "The reference already exists...": Exit Sub
  Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox """Microsoft Scripting Runtime"" reference added successfully..."
  End If
End Sub
```

The code could be designed to not need the reference, but it is good to have acces to the intellisense suggestion for the dictionary object, I think.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @Joe_ft Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need? A little feedback did not kill anybody...